# Async-Await Still running asynchronously

Tags: node.js, sqlite, promise, async-await

Awaiting Select * function then doing stuff after its done printing. 
But its rushing right past the await doing everything after then printing the output. so its sort of going: calls Await function then other stuff after await runs before resolve is called then prints out await function.

I honestly have tried alot. making anonymous async block to run the awaits inside a function. i wasn't using promises for functions before but then added them thinking i needed to resolve them. but no dice.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db = new sqlite3.Database(__dirname+'/requestLog.db');

test();
async function test(){
    await selectAll();

    console.log('test')
}

function selectAll(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            db.serialize(function() {   
                db.each("SELECT rowid AS id,* FROM requests", function(err, row) {
                    console.log(row);  
                });
                resolve()
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error With Select ALL(): \r\n ${error}`)
            reject();
        }
    });
 }
```

Im sure its just me missing something ridiculous. 
and now i feel like im going down a rabit hole and going around in circles 
please dont judge me lol

I wanted to print everything in the database to the console. And then do the ("test")or anything after i print it.

but everything runs right through the await

Comment: Move the `resolve()` into the callback of the `db.each()`.  It won't wait for the `db.each()` to finish otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `resolve()` being called after `db.each()`, the right place to put the resolve would be the complete callback: `Database#each(sql, [param, ...], [callback], [complete])`, from the docs. 
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete

```
function selectAll() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            db.serialize(function () {
                db.each("SELECT rowid AS id,* FROM requests", function (err, row) {
                    console.log(row);
                },
                    (err, rowCount) => {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        resolve(rowCount);
                    }
                );
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error With Select ALL(): \r\n ${error}`)
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ayyy that did it. Thank you so much. the DB im making was simple so i was following the usage examples in the readme. I didnt notice that part. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
async function selectAll() {
    await  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id,* FROM requests", function (err, row) {
        console.log(row);
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to name the function, but you do need the `async` flag.

Comment: `db.each` doesn't return a Promise in this library.  This code won't make a difference.

Comment: Thanks i tried but it still logs that test before it prints.